# FOO = {M | |L(M)| < ∞} What does this turing machine defines?

Tags: turing-machines

FOO = {M | The length of language that M accepts is less than infinity} 
M: a turing machine 
M such that |L(M)| is less than inifinity: a turing machine such that the length of the language that the machine accepts, is less than infinity. 
For example, We have |M1| <3, it means this TM only accepts less than three words, but the length of each word can be more than 3 letters.

a) the set of Turing machine descriptions that accept only finitely many inputs 
b) the set of Turing machine decriptions that accept all their inputs. 
c) the set of Turing machine descriptions that accept infinitely many different inputs

I struggle between the three answers, as I do not really understand what does infinity means here. The length of the language is less than infinity, so my initial thought is that the turing machine only accepts finitely many inputs --a).

Later, I think there are different levels of infinity, and less than infinity means I can approach to infinity indefinitely, and thus the turing machine can accept infinity many inputs. And I begin to struggle between b) and c).

Could someone shed light on it?

Comment: Hi! I think there is one vertical bar too many or too few in your notation. I think you meant: {M such that |L(M)| < ∞ }. Also, I assume "L(M)" is something that has been defined in your class. Could you please include this definition? An important part of the question is understanding what "|L(M)| < ∞" means, which starts by understanding what "L(M)" means.

Comment: *"The length of the language is less than infinity, so my initial thought is that the turing machine only accepts finitely many inputs"*  Yes! That understanding is correct.

Comment: Regarding the question in the title: *"What does this turing machine defines?"*. Foo is not a Turing machine. Foo is a set. A set of Turing machines. A given Turing machine M is in the set Foo if and only if |L(M)| < ∞.

Comment: *"Later, I think there are different levels and infinity, and less than infinity means I can approach to infinity indefinitely, and thus the turing machine can accept infinity many inputs."* No. "|L(M)| < ∞" is just shorthand notation to mean "L(M) is a finite set". For every given Turing machine M, |L(M)| is a precise number, and doesn't "approach" infinity. However, the set Foo contains infinitely many Turing machines, and yes, it contains a machine M such that |L(M)| = 10, and another machine M such that |L(M)| = 100, and another machine M such that |L(M)| = 1000, etc

Comment: Ah! I see, thank you for the clearification about infinity! And I think I also miss the part that this defines a set of TM

Comment: { } are most often used to define sets. { n in N | 2 divides N } is the set of all even numbers. { M | |L(M)| < ∞ } is the set of Turing machines that accept finite languages.

Comment: Thank you, it's super helpful! Let me digest it!